# Google custom search: Looking for example of retrieving search results

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-custom-search

Following the example written in [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/customSearch/index.php).

1. How can I retrieve each of the search result URL, anybody has an idea?
2. How can I limit the search result to lets say 5 results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How can I retrieve each of the search result URL, anybody has an
>      idea?

[Here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list) you find the description of the reponse object, the search result URLs are in items[].link

> 2. How can I limit the search result to lets say 5 results?

You can pass a "num" parameter

[image]

RTM :P

Comment: By the way do you know if it's okay that results I get through this api are not the same as I search for through google.com?
My custom search is searching in google.com, but when browsing to google.com and after enetering the same phrase - different results appear

Comment: Google use additional metadata based on the user that gse, in my opinion, doesn't use :)